# Ionic CLI start project error

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm having a few questions and problems. I'm using the CLI I went with the choice of tabs. when I start a project I get back these errors is there any way you can give me some input please?

> npm i
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):
>
> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/nod...
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/nod...":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall
>   C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>   node lib/post_install.js
>
> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose
--libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe',
gyp verb cli

'C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js',

gyp verb cli 'rebuild',

gyp verb cli '--verbose',

gyp verb cli '--libsass_ext=',

gyp verb cli '--libsass_cflags=',

gyp verb cli '--libsass_ldflags=',

gyp verb cli '--libsass_library=' ]

gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2

gyp info using node@9.3.0 | win32 | x64

gyp verb command rebuild []

gyp verb command clean []

gyp verb clean removing "build" directory

gyp verb command configure []

gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH

gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2

gyp verb `which` failed at getNotFoundError

(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed at F

(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed at E

(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed at

C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed at

C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed at

C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)

gyp verb `which` failed python2 { Error: not found: python2

gyp verb `which` failed at getNotFoundError

(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed at F

(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed at E

(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n at getNotFoundError
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)\n at F
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)\n at E
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)\n at
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16\n at
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5\n at
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5\n at
FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed at getNotFoundError
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed at F (C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed at E (C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed at getNotFoundError
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed at F (C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed at E (C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed stack: 'Error: not found: python\n at getNotFoundError
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)\n at F
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)\n at E
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)\n at
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16\n at
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5\n at
C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5\n at
FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.failNoPython
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.
(C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack at C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe"
"C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
"--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\webde\Desktop\ionicProjects\tryApp\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v9.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\webde\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-01-02T16_46_21_131Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, but someone also posted this problem as an issue in the "sass/node-sass" repo on github: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2200.

**Update:** If you're using node 9, the problem is the fact that node-sass isn't compatible with it (see https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-installing-ionic-and-starting-a-project/116887).

Using node LTS (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.9.0/) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Ok great Thanks for the quick response Let me look into this and see if any of this works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the input I uninstalled node 9 and installed node LTS and things worked great for me. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem, mate. Don't forget to accept the answer as the solution, if it worked for you :)